# How to build Node js app in production for hosting in IIS

Tags: node.js, iis, build, production-environment

I have a node js server that I want to deploy on IIS. Since I am new to node, I am unable to understand the following:

- How to bring the code in production mode?
- How to build the code in production mode?
- How to deploy it to IIS

Thank you

Comment: I think each of the questions have been discussed already on Stack Overflow, so why posting again? Unless you have something new to say.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below steps to deploy the node js app in iis:
1)Install iisnode
https://github.com/Azure/iisnode

2)Download and install url rewrite extension

3)set the port number in your node app by using below code:
process.env.PORT
note: use the same port number in iis site bindings

4)add the site in iis and give your node js app folder path and set the site bindings

5)Add below code in web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system. Webserver>
    <handlers>
        <add name=""iisnode"" path=""server.js"" verb=""*"" modules=""iisnode"" />
    </handlers>
   <rewrite>
        <rules>
        <rule name=""rule1"">
            <match url=""/*"" />
            <action type=""Rewrite"" url=""server.js"" />
        </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
    </system. Webserver>
</configuration>
```

Note: please give the iis_iusrs and iusr full control permission to the site root folder

Comment: that is true but my question is that how can I build my node js server's code for production. I am unable to build it for production at the moment

Comment: @RameenAkhter you can try this command 'npm run build', may I know which node app you are using?